# jQuery incrementally count selected checkbox and deselected checkbox

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have an ASP.NET web form that has 6 checkbox. 1 checkbox is to call a Function to select all checkbox and show the message "You have selected" 6 "items" (in this case, 6 checkbox). If a user doesn't select the Select All checkbox, they can select or deselect other checkbox individually and the message will be "You have selected" # "items" I'm trying to do this in jQuery, but it's not working yet. Here's the script:

```
    <script  type="text/javascript">
    //This function works on the click event of SelectAll checkbox
    function selectAll(involker) {
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', $(involker).attr('checked'));

        var count = $(":checkbox:checked").length;
        $("#selectedCheckboxMessage").html(count).css({ 'background-color': '#228B22', 'font-weight': 'bolder', 'color': '#FFFFFF', 'padding-left': '0.5em', 'padding-right': '0.5em' });

    }

    //Not working, the message wont's show up on the click event of the checkbox
    $(function() {

        $("input[id ^= ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlTimeSheet_ctl]").click(showCheckboxStatus);

    });

    function showCheckboxStatus(evt) {

        var numSelected = $(":checkbox:checked").length;
        $("#selectedCheckboxMessage").html("You have selected " + numSelected).css({ 'background-color': '#228B22', 'font-weight': 'bolder', 'color': '#FFFFFF', 'padding-left': '0.5em', 'padding-right': '0.5em' });

    }
```

The message shows only when a SelectAll checkbox is selected. The message doesn't show if other checkbox is selected or deselected.

I look for an checkbox Id $("input[id ^= ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlTimeSheet_ctl]") instead of looking for a CSS class. On the markup

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbMarkAsComplete" runat="server" CssClass ="CheckBoxClass"   />
```

will make the following HTML output:

```
<span class="CheckBoxClass"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dlTimeSheet$ctl00$cbMarkAsComplete" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dlTimeSheet_ctl00_cbMarkAsComplete"></span>
```

The CSS class CheckBoxClass is not with the HTML input, that's why I'm looking for checkbox  Id instead of checkbox class.

Thank you for the input.

Comment: I admit it, I read it three times and still I can't understand what exactly is working and what not.

Comment: Here's the mark-up to select all the checkbox, and it show the message properly
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbMarkAll" runat="server" OnClick="selectAll(this)" 
                    Text="Select All" TextAlign="Left" />

But other checkbox is not working, either it's selected or deselected the message won't show up. OnClick event of the other checkbox is not working I think. I don't really know where's the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

To return just the number of selected checkboxes on the page try changing your selector around a bit and using something like this

```
$("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length
```

That should give you the number of checked checkboxes.

```
$("input:checked").length
```

Will also work but Im a dork for specificity.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using a selector like `$('.CheckBoxClass input:checkbox')`

As for your problem of the number not updating, I'm looking at this line:

```
var numSelected = $("input.myCheckbox:checked").length;
```

I don't see the .myCheckbox class anywhere.  Try this:

```
var numSelected = $('.CheckBoxClass input:checked').length;
```